# Getting undefined when updating array in stores using Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am learning Svelte and how to make custom stores using it. I've come across a problem where when I try to update a writable array using update, it causes an undefined error in components that subscribe to the array.

Here is my store where I have a simple array with one element, a string:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const activeData = writable(["array"])
```

Here is a component that updates the store. I am simply pushing the word "pushed" to the activeData array:

```
<script>
import {activeData} from './Store.js'

let handlePush = ()=>{
    activeData.update(val=>{val.push('pushed!')
    val = val
}
    )
}

</script>

<button
on:click={handlePush}>
push
</button>
```

And then in this app.svelte component, I am subscribing to activeData and hoping to print the elements of the activeData array using Svelte's #each directive:

```
<script>
    import {activeData} from './Store.js'
    import Push from './Push.svelte'
    

</script>

<div>
   {#each $activeData as datum}
    <p>{datum}</p>
    {/each}

    {@debug $activeData}
</div>

<Push/>
```

When I check the console for activeData, I see that it updates by adding "Push!" to the array. However, I then get an error in my app.svelte component saying "Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects."

So after updating the array, the array is no longer an array to components subscribing to it.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update callback should return the new value, in your case you'r returning `undefined`, try:

```
activeData.update(val => [...val, 'pushed!'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it. Instead of using update, I directly accessed the store value and just manipulated it there.

```
$activeData = [...$activeData, 'pushed!']
```

This fixed my issue. I just couldn't get it to work with the update method.